# What to do about error in Jenkins pipeline Process working directory '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<yourpipelinenamehere> doesn't exist

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, workspace

I have found this question asked in various places in various forms and even fought it myself.
I believe that I have found the solution for the scenario in which I have encountered this and am curious if it helps others who similarly encounter this.

The short answer of what i found to do, is set the first stage of my pipeline to a known module that has logic to create the workspace. I.E. the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Opening Workspace') {
           steps {
               script {
                   def date = new Date()
                   def data = "I am arbitrary text\nSecond line\n" + date
                   writeFile(file: 'workspacecreated.txt', text: data)
                   sh "ls -l"
               }
           }
       }
        stage('alltherest') {
<< the rest of your steps and end of your pipeline to paste here>>
```

In my case of fighting this, My first stage was `ansiblePlaybook()` which, as it turns out... does not seem to try and create this workspace. I have filed this as a bug in jenkins against the ansible plugin.

So the first question is,
If you hit this error message in jenkins, does setting the first step to writefile help you?
If so what was your original first step? Perhaps you should post that first steps plugin failing to create a workspace for itself as a bug to jenkins.

The second question is,
Does anyone have a more elegant solution of this workaround?

Comment: Unless what you are doing in your stage actually requires a workspace, it won't get created.

Comment: @IanW Unfortunately ansiblePlaybook() does require a workspace, but it does not try to create one. This causes the jenkins project to fail immediately with error "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/projectname doesn't exist"

Answer (score 1):

1. create folder /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/projectname
2. change ownership of folder to jenkins user
3. Add line `sh 'cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/projectname'` in the steps block i.e

`steps { sh 'cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/projectname' script { .................` 
Do this at the first time when running a pipeline after installation of jenkins, you don't need to do this after that